# Laravel 4.2 filter - "Trying to get property of non-object" Error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, filter, laravel-5

I am trying to create a filter in Laravel so that only admins are allowed to access some URLs.

What I have done is,

```
    Route::filter('admin', function()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->permission != -1)
        {
            if (Request::ajax())
            {
                return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::guest('/');
            }
        }
    });
```

in the **app/filters.php** file.

But I am getting an eror like this if I try yo access admin's url-

[image: Screenshot]

Users table is like this-

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone help please?

Comment: `laravel-4` or `laravel-5`?

Comment: Does this work if you are sure that the user is signed in? If they aren't signed in, `Auth::user()` will not have any properties (it will be a non-object, in other words)

Comment: Try dd(Auth::user());, see if the user is logged in. Or just try changing your condition to if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->permission != -1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Auth::user()` is null. `Auth::user()` is only available when the user is logged in. You will need to do `Auth::check()` first before calling anything on the intended user model

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    if (!Auth::check() || Auth::user()->permission != -1)
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('/');
        }
    }
});
```